# Comparing Identical Images in Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, ssim

I'm trying to make a program that will identify Minecraft blocks based on an image. I currently have an image being cut up in 16x16 images and being compared to the texture files which should be identical. I can't seem to find a good solution to comparing the images. I've tried openCV and Pillow, haven't been able to get one that is accurate. Just looking for any suggestions.

Comment: What happens if you open the files with `open`?

Comment: @Josh I have the texture files saved in a folder, but the 16x16 cut image isn't been saved. It just gets cut and then compared to each texture until it finds a match.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Could look at cosine similarity algorithm. Gives you a score of how similar two vectors are. An image could be flattened to a vector. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You can do template matching or you can use structural similarity index (ssim from skimage)

Comment: @MarcusRenshaw It looks a little out of my level right now, but I'll definitely keep it in mind. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @fmw42 I tried the SSIM it worked great, thanks!